# Can I still release a product with iText 2.1.5?

Tags: itext

I can not find any link related with 2.1.5 from SourceForge. I wonder whether I can still use this version as a third party component in my product.

Any comment would be appreciated very much!

Comment: Read http://itextpdf.com/salesfaq and you'll understand why all versions prior to iText 5 (and all 5.2.x) versions have been removed from SourceForge.

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can. Search the web and you will find that version easily (e.g. [here](http://olex.openlogic.com/packages/itext/2.1.7) or [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.lowagie/itext/2.1.7)) It is a different question however whether you should still use that version. It is quite old and lots of bugs have been fixed and new functionality has been added. So do the following:

- check the license restrictions (LGPL vs. AGPL)
- if you don't have a problem with a GPL based license then use the latest 5.X version
- if you can't use APGL buy a commercial license or use at least version 2.1.7
- if you go the 2.1.7 route do some testing - in many cases it will do its job still fine. If not you'll probably have to fix it by yourself

Update: I would now use [openPDF](https://github.com/LibrePDF/OpenPDF) which is a maintained fork based on 2.1.7.